# Value can not be null exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following code reads a dataset from a stored procedure and than I am saving it in a list. Dataset from stored procedure is working fine, it returns table with values. But I keep getting exception when saving it into a List.

The code is

```
    public class mList
        {
            public DateTime Ee { get; set; }
            public DateTime ndate { get; set; }
            public int SNo { get; set; }
            public int CId { get; set; }
            public int rID { get; set; }
        }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
     string procName = "listest";
                SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(cs);
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    ds.Tables["t0"].TableName = "Rows";

        List<mL> newlist = ds.Tables["t0"].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new mList
        {
            Ee = row.Field<DateTime?>(0).GetValueOrDefault(),
            ndate = row.Field<DateTime?>(1).GetValueOrDefault(),
            SNo = row.Field<int?>(2).GetValueOrDefault(),
            CId = row.Field<int?>(3).GetValueOrDefault(),
            rID = row.Field<int?>(4).GetValueOrDefault()
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Exception I get is `System.ArgumentNullException was caught, Message=Value cannot be null.`

Comment: Have/Can you debug in and checked those values during runtime?

Comment: What's the definition for `mList`?  Does it permit NULLs?

Comment: I hope you checked this already (it isn't clear from your question), but is the table in your dataset really named `"t0"`?

Comment: This is the defination of mList
public class mList
    {
        public DateTime Ee { get; set; }
        public DateTime ndate { get; set; }
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public int CId { get; set; }
        public int rID { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Perhaps try breaking apart the LINQ query to determine which part of it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to replicate your problem and it looks like your table name needs to be "Rows" and not "t0". You rename the table higher up in your code. Someone in the comments already mentioned this. I re-created your example in a console application and the below works:

Note: the example is based on some assumptions.
Your data types are correct that the query is returning based on the mList object definition. I can assume this because if they were not, you would get a cast exception.

```
class Program
{
    public class mList
    {
        public DateTime Ee { get; set; }
        public DateTime ndate { get; set; }
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public int CId { get; set; }
        public int rID { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable t = new DataTable("Rows");
        t.Columns.Add("ee", typeof(DateTime));
        t.Columns.Add("ndate", typeof(DateTime));
        t.Columns.Add("sno", typeof(int));
        t.Columns.Add("cid", typeof(int));
        t.Columns.Add("rid", typeof(int));

        t.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 0, 1, null);
        t.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 2, 1, 2);
        t.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 4, 1, 1);
        t.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, 5, 1, 1);

        ds.Tables.Add(t);

        //IF TABLE IS t0 - You get a null reference exception
        List<mList> newlist = ds.Tables["Rows"].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new mList
        {
            Ee = row.Field<DateTime?>(0).GetValueOrDefault(),
            ndate = row.Field<DateTime?>(1).GetValueOrDefault(),
            SNo = row.Field<int?>(2).GetValueOrDefault(),
            CId = row.Field<int?>(3).GetValueOrDefault(),
            rID = row.Field<int?>(4).GetValueOrDefault()
        }).ToList();
    }

}
```

Below is an example using a stored procedure. Note my initial table name is Table and not t0.

The stored procedure is a mockedup stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListTest
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  GETDATE()+1 AS EE
            ,GETDATE()-1 AS ndate
            ,1 AS SNo,2 AS CId,NULL AS rID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  GETDATE()+1
            ,GETDATE()-1
            ,1 ,2, 2
    UNION ALL --TEST WITH ALL NULL VALUES
    SELECT  NULL
            ,NULL
            ,NULL ,NULL, NULL
END
```

The altered console application using c#:

```
string procName = "listtest";
string cs = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;";
SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(cs);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ds.Tables["Table"].TableName = "Rows";

List<mList> newlist = ds.Tables["Rows"].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new mList
{
    Ee = row.Field<DateTime?>(0).GetValueOrDefault(),
    ndate = row.Field<DateTime?>(1).GetValueOrDefault(),
    SNo = row.Field<int?>(2).GetValueOrDefault(),
    CId = row.Field<int?>(3).GetValueOrDefault(),
    rID = row.Field<int?>(4).GetValueOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Code looks fine but it is not filling the data from stored procedure as in my code I am getting data from stored procedure